# Extracting minutes for the attached query

Tags: sql

I have the following query which is working fine.

However, I would like the columns as shown in the attachment to only show the times as "minutes".

Please could someone advise me on what I should to achieve this?
Once again, thank you for your kind help!

[image]

```
USE CBS_AFRICA_LIVECOPY

SELECT FOLIO_NUMBER, FORMAT(ORDER_ENTRY_TIME, 'hh:MM') AS ORDER_ENTRY_TIME, 
    FORMAT(START_LOAD_TIME, 'hh:MM') as START_LOAD_TIME, 
    (ORDER_ENTRY_TIME - START_LOAD_TIME) AS STAGING_MINUTES, 
    (TERM_END_LOAD_TIME - START_LOAD_TIME) AS LOADING_MINUTES,
    (TERM_END_LOAD_TIME - ORDER_ENTRY_TIME) AS TERMINAL_MINUTES,
    FORMAT(TERM_END_LOAD_TIME, 'hh:MM') as TERM_END_LOAD 
FROM ORDERS    
WHERE LOADING_TERMINAL_ID = '11011'
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL, SQL Server ? What is the format of your dates ?

Comment: format of the dates are yyyymmdd / 00:00:00:000 , but only want to extract the minutes from the query result as per my screenshot.  Don't need the date as I work on the folio numbers as my date.

Comment: Sorry, it also gives an error when if I keep the AS staging minutes etc in the query.

Comment: You tried what did i answered ? If yes what is the error ?

Comment: Fixed, I had to remove the opening brackets between minute, (order_entry_time etc).

Comment: So is it working now ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DATEPART()` for extract the minutes from the `DATETIME` :

```
USE CBS_AFRICA_LIVECOPY;

SELECT FOLIO_NUMBER, FORMAT(ORDER_ENTRY_TIME, 'hh:MM') AS ORDER_ENTRY_TIME, 
    FORMAT(START_LOAD_TIME, 'hh:MM') as START_LOAD_TIME, 
    DATEPART(MINUTE, (ORDER_ENTRY_TIME - START_LOAD_TIME) AS STAGING_MINUTES, 
    DATEPART(MINUTE, (TERM_END_LOAD_TIME - START_LOAD_TIME)) AS LOADING_MINUTES,
    DATEPART(MINUTE, (TERM_END_LOAD_TIME - ORDER_ENTRY_TIME)) AS TERMINAL_MINUTES,
    FORMAT(TERM_END_LOAD_TIME, 'hh:MM') as TERM_END_LOAD 
FROM ORDERS    
WHERE LOADING_TERMINAL_ID = '11011';
```

If you are using MySQL you can use the EXTRACT function.

Comment: Yes sir it is, one last question why do I need to have the following command at the end of my query, if I put it at the beginning with the others?    FORMAT(TERM_END_LOAD_TIME, 'hh:MM') as TERM_END_LOAD  Msg 321, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
"minute" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90

Comment: I dont know for your last question but if my answer helped you, you can mark it as a good anwser. If you have another question do another post.